# RewriteRule from download.php?token=something into /download/something

Tags: .htaccess

I am working on url, I try htaccess, php, javascript and many other things but unable to figure it out.

My url is :

```
 example/cheap-flight-to.php?country=lagos
```

and I want to change the url something like this :

```
 example/cheap-flight-to.lagos
```

or

```
 example/cheap-flight-to/lagos
```

please help me

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also why is javascript & jQuery tagged in this. Please remove unnecessary/non-related tags.

Answer (score 1):

The following should allow you to generate your urls in the format that you wish.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^example/cheap-flight-to/([a-zA-Z]+)$ /example/cheap-flight-to.php?country=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

What you want could be done using regular expressions in .htaccess, but it makes no sence, since it wouldn't be pointing to anything, unless you have a directory cheap-flight-to/lago in which you have an index.php that will show-up in the browser or return data. This means you have to setup a directory for each destination you want to go to. Is that really what you want? Usually it's been used the otherway around. The user (or a script for that matter) enters a url like "example/cheap-flight-to/lagos". Then through regular expressions in .htaccess you rewrite the url to "example/cheap-flight-to.php?country=lagos".

Have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/misc/rewriteguide.html and
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html for more on rewriting rules in .htaccess.